# How to use else statement in this PHP script to echo HTML table

Tags: php, html

This script works well unless you put two URLS in that do not have meta tags, then they render in html all wrong.

How can I use the else statement in it so it will stop?

If you want to test it go here: http://php-playground.co.cc/testdir/metaex.php

```
<form method="get" action=<?php echo "'".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'";?> >
<p>URL of Competitor:</p> 
<textarea name="siteurl" rows="10" cols="50">
<?php //Check if the form has already been submitted and if this is the case, display the     submitted content. If not, display 'http://'.
echo (isset($_GET['siteurl']))?htmlspecialchars($_GET['siteurl']):"http://";?>
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="nofloat"></div>
<table>
<?php
function parseUrl($url){
    //Trim whitespace of the url to ensure proper checking.
    $url = trim($url);
    //Check if a protocol is specified at the beginning of the url. If it's not,    prepend 'http://'.
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
            $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    //Check if '/' is present at the end of the url. If not, append '/'.
    if (substr($url, -1)!=="/"){
            $url .= "/";
    }
    //Return the processed url.
    return $url;
}
//If the form was submitted
if(isset($_GET['siteurl'])){
    //Put every new line as a new entry in the array
    $urls = explode("\n",trim($_GET["siteurl"]));
    //Iterate through urls
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
            //Parse the url to add 'http://' at the beginning or '/' at the end if not   already there, to avoid errors with the get_meta_tags function
            $url = parseUrl($url);
            //Get the meta data for each url
            $tags = get_meta_tags($url);
            //Check to see if the description tag was present and adjust output   accordingly
            echo (isset($tags['description']))?"<tr><td>Description($url)</td>  <td>".$tags['description']:"Description($url)</td><td>No Meta Description</td></tr>.";
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: The part I need help with is echo'ing the table :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiple ways to do this; why don't you use simpler way to do this

```
$tags = NULL;
$tags = get_meta_tags($url);
if($tags)
echo "<tr><td>Description($url)</td><td>" .$tags['description']. "</td></tr>";
else 
echo "<tr><td>Description($url)</td<td>No Meta Description</td></tr>";
```

or if you want to stick with your code try this, need to have staring and ending tags for both true and false;

```
echo (isset($tags['description'])) ? '<tr><td>Description($url)</td><td>' . $tags['description'] . '</td></tr>' : '<tr><td>Description($url)</td><td>No Meta Description</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the last dot `.` in the line :

`echo (isset($tags['description']))?"<tr><td>Description($url)</td>  <td>".$tags['description']:"Description($url)</td><td>No Meta Description</td></tr>.";`

EDIT :
I haven't seen this but you have one more error in this line :
Replace `".$tags['description']:"` by `".$tags['description'].":`